# How to extract sub-pattern from javascript regex matched pattern

Tags: javascript, regex-group

How to extract sub-pattern from javascript regex matched pattern.

```
//string: 
var str = textcircle c360 s270 ar2 bl2px_br2px_ml0_mr0;

//matching conditions:
var ang = c.match( /c(\d+)\s+/g ); //matches c360
var startang = c.match( /s(\d+)\s+/g ); //matches s180
var ar = c.match( /ar(\d+)\s+/g );  //matches ["ar2 "]
```

In case of `ang`, i need extract only `(\d+)` subpattern, the number 360, not full `c360`.

In case of `startang`, i need extract only `(\d+)` subpattern, the number 180, not full `s180`.

In case of `ar`, i need extract only `(\d+)` subpattern, the number 2, not full `ar2`, for some reason it is returned as an array, not as a string.

Answer (score 1):

`regexpattern.exec(string)` returns an array with 0th item the whole match and 1st item the  first group. In this scenario you need 1st group

```js
//string: 
var str = 'textcircle c270 s270 ar2 bl2px_br2px_ml0_mr0;'

//matching conditions:
var ang = /c(\d+)\s+/g.exec(str)[1]; //matches 270
var startang = /s(\d+)\s+/g.exec(str)[1]; //matches 270
var ar = /ar(\d+)\s+/g.exec(str)[1]; //matches 2

console.log(ang)
console.log(startang)
console.log(ar)
```

Comment: @olga Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.